# JQuery.BootGrid data types and data formatters

Tags: jquery, jqgrid-formatter, jquery-bootgrid

What data types and data formatters are available with JQuery.BootGrid? 
Or are the data-type and data-formatter fields actutally JQuery DataTypes or some other property?  If so what are the JQuery DataTypes?  (I couldn't find documentation about that)

I want to set a column as currency (with a dollar sign to the left), how do I do that with JQuery.BootGrid?

But I want to understand the data-type/data-formatter in general. Do I have to understand jqGrid formatter for that, or is bootGrid a totally different product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Bootgrid data-type:**

Turns out  `data-type="numeric"`  is the only type supported:

From [results on a search on the bootgrid github](https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-bootgrid/blob/ada3cee7feb3259d90f8cbab6d630214cfa16b5e/CHANGELOG.md) I understand that there is only one explicit  type supported: **numeric**, anything else is a javascript string.

The numeric data-type is used with the internal "numeric" converter - to and from a string.

(In the question I meant JQuery datatypes [defined here (click on this)](https://api.jquery.com/Types/), but as I just said, these have nothing to do with Bootgrid)

**Using the Bootgrid formatter**

I understand that the formatter is just any html with the use of "this" and the grid objects ([see here in the Bootgrid docs](https://api.jquery.com/Types/) then scroll down to "Formatters").

So you can write code like this:

```
// ... in continuation to the .bootgrid
$("#grid").bootgrid({
    formatters: {
        dollarformatter: function (column, row){
            // "this" - is mapped to the grid instance
            return '$ ' + this.rows[row][column]; 
        },
        myformatter: function (column, row)
        {
            // "this" - is mapped to the grid instance
            // text - here is defined by the next column's content
            return '<button id=\"mybutton' + row + '\"'
                   + ' type=\"button\"'
                   + ' class=\"btn btn-primary\"'
                   + ' onclick=\"mybuttonclicked(' + row + ')\"'
                   + '>'
                   + this.rows[row][column + 1]
                   + '</button>';
        }
    }
});
```

I'm not a front-end javascript expert, so if there's a clearer way to write those lines of code without all the escapes, please tell me about it here.

Thank you.

Comment: related question of mine:  Will bootgrid work with non-numeric column-id as the data-identifier

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203560/will-bootgrid-work-with-non-numeric-column-id-as-data-identifier

Answer (score 4):

Actually I've been using jquery bootgrid for the last 8 months and Using its formatter function to reformat any columns.

**In the js file:**

```
$("#grid").bootgrid({
  money: function(column, row) {
    return '$ '+row[column.id];
  },
  priceFormat: function(column, row) {
    return '<span class="price-format">'+row[column.id]+'</span>';
  }
});
```

**In the html:**

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th data-column-id="id" data-identifier="true" data-type="numeric">ID</th>
    <th data-column-id="nama">Nama</th>
    <th data-column-id="merk">Merk</th>
    <th data-column-id="harga_limit" data-formatter="money">Harga Limit</th>
    <th data-column-id="harga_satuan" data-formatter="money">Harga Satuan</th>
    <th data-column-id="harga_total" data-formatter="priceFormat">Total</th>
  <tr>
</thead>
```

Comment: So instead of what I wrote in my answer: 'this.rows[row, column]' you can write 'row[column.id]' ?