# Will bootgrid work with non-numeric column-id as data-identifier

Tags: jquery-bootgrid

will bootgrid work with non numeric column-id as the identifier, if its a unique value?

```
<th data-column-id="mytextid" data-identifier="true">Unique Text ID</th>
```

Will selection="true" work for instance?  Or do I need a numeric value for the identifier column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK tried it in fiddle. **You can have a non numeric data-identifier**. (IMHO it should be called *data-row-identifier*...)

In order to access that column you simply use the name you set in the data-column-identifier, so:

```
        <!-- works!! even without data-type="numeric" -->
        <th data-column-id="myid" data-identifier="true">My ID</th>
        <th data-column-id="info">Info</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

and the code should be

```
    $("#mygrid").bootgrid(
    {
        // other settings... and: 
        selection: true
    }).on("selected.rs.jquery.bootgrid", function(e, rows)
    {
        alert("Selected: " + rows[0].myid);
    });
```

[Here's a jsfiddle to prove the point](http://jsfiddle.net/yvypgvm7/)